# Report server (SSRS) email delivery delayed for 10 hours

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subscription

Weird thing happened the other day.
Around 2 am there are lots of subscriptions fires on report server that sends emails.
Users received some of them, but not all.
Then around noon, all of the sudden users started to receive bunch of emails.

It turned out those were emails that supposed to be delivered at 2 am, however, the delay took around 10 hours (till noon).

It seems like subscriptions did the job and fired emails, but those emails were queued somewhere for such long period of time, then delivered all at the same time.

I looked at ExecutionLog1, 2 and 3. Looks all normal. Between start and end only 3 seconds.

[image]

Agent job also fine. Finished successfully at 2 am.

What could cause such a huge delay in email delivery?

It happened on Monday, which can be busy but not as busy as it would be at the end of the month.

Where else should I look for a reason?

Comment: Your email server

Comment: Thanks. Will look into that.

Comment: SMTP mail is not a guaranteed delivery mechanism, nor is it guaranteed to be prompt. Maybe the receiving MTA has some kind of greylisting/spam control mechanism that delays delivery of things it considers to be spam, so the messages were queued up on the sending MTA.